# How to bind `this` into an function argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, bind

I have search and try few method, like directly using `app.shadow.dialogue({...}.bind(this))` but getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.bind is not a function

And trying to do this instead

```
let dialogue = {
  "title": {
    "text": "Kembali ke tes?",
    "description": "Anda memiliki tes yang masih berlangsung"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "text": "Ya",
      "class": "bg-safe",
      "icon": "refresh",
      "action": "direct/tes"
    },{
      "text": "Tidak, Lihat Hasil Sebelumnya",
      "class": "bg-danger",
      "icon": "close",
      "action": function() {
        app.shadow.stop();
        this.view();
      }
    }
  ]
};

dialogue.actions[1].action.bind(this);
app.shadow.dialogue(dialogue);
```

but `this.view` still not get into scope

> Uncaught TypeError: this.view is not a function

Is there a way to make `this` statement useable inside an object argument?

Comment: Where is the `view` method defined? And what is `this` at the time of doing `.bind(this)`?

Comment: `dialogue.actions[1].action.bind(this);` returns a new function, it doesn't update `action`, so `dialogue` is the same object as it was even without `.bind()` being called. You would need to update it to hold the new function `dialogue.actions[1].action = dialogue.actions[1].action.bind(this);`, or, just us an arrow function for `action` - this all assumes that `view()` is defined on the `this` value from the surrounding scope of where `dialogue` has been delcared.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try :

```
`
"action":()=> {
        app.shadow.stop();
        this.view();
      }`
```

hope this is useful for you.